# I wiped everything from my phone with TWRP and my version is too old

Tags: twrp, 5.1-lollipop, system

i have a few ROMs and some backups in my computer so I tried to flash them but I always get "Error executing updater binary in zip" which I heard means my version is too old.

EDIT: I tried to flash them with adb sideload which is the only way adb recognizes the device. I can't really boot on bootloader either

I got a linux, and a windows with SDK is there anything I can do to recover my phone?

Comment: How did you try to flash them? Please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: Is there a way to install a new version of TWRP from adb sideload + Twrp sideload?

Comment: Usually you install TWRP via fastboot.

Comment: Flash a new version of TWRP with fastboot... Otherwise if you have a OpenRecovery flashable version of latest TWRP for your device, just copy it over to your internal storage and flash it with TWRP. Neat think about TWRP, you can write your recovery from recovery, then just Reboot - Recovery. For a more detailed answer, we would need to know 1) Your EXACT device and 2) Your current TWRP version

Comment: My device is a Alcatel Onetouch (OT) Pixi 3 4.5 4G (5017A) a Lollipop. My TWRP is super OLD is a OTO I believe it is before version 3.0.0 I have the .img of TWRP 3.0.0 that fits my device (on my computer).

Comment: Can SP flashtool be useful here?

Comment: Flash the new TWRP with the old TWRP ... Then try.

Comment: Hang On..... DO YOU HAVE A WORKING TWRP, AND A BACKUP MADE BY THAT TWRP ?

Comment: Please have a look at this video on MTK firmware backup's and restoration using SP Flash Tool v5.17 and above.

Comment: It saves me writing everything twice https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=e2_U68EGSlY

Comment: I have a backup made by that TRWP in my computer. But, as mentioned above my computer can't see my phone

Comment: Thanks for the video, but BOOT_1, BOOT_2 and USER are empty as I couldn't do the readback, so I can't restore just like that I still think if there is a solution it will come from SP flash